# How to use ANTLR to parse "vector<int>(10)"?

Tags: antlr3

I'm trying to use ANTLR3 to parse some C++ codes.

I want to parse template in C++.
But I got some troubles when I am trying to parse this:

```
vector<int>(10)
```

I found this is a legal input without template syntax, because my parse thought this code was just:

```
(vector < int) > (10)
```

My parser thinks this is just two compare operators.

This does make sense but didn't meet my expectations.

Actually, what I thought this code should be parse in this way:

```
(vector<int>)(10)
```

How should I handle the operator precedence? Thank you very much!

Update: The final solution is to use predicate.

Comment: Can you post your grammar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing expressions rules you should probably parse `< type >` at a higher precedence level than operators. This way the parser first tries to complete this rule before it goes finding something else.

Comment: I'd recommend not to use backtracking if you can avoid it. Backtracking can solve tricky problems, no doubt, but it also adds new problems, like less control over the parsing path taken or producing mostly useless error messages if something goes wrong. My suggestion above was to restructure your grammar so that you can ensure a certain order in parsing.

Comment: But in this case, input like "vector<int>(10)" is ambiguous, the  grammar can still be LL(1)?